# How to check strength (intensity) of audio while recording?

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am working on a voice recorder application. I want to know is there any way to find strength of the audio while recording it. I don't want to save the recording anywhere. I just want to show user if the sound being caught by the mic is louder then a predefined threshold or not.

Let's say if the sound being caught in below 2 decibel, it should show "low" in a red canvas. As soon as sound gets louder and passes 2 decibel threshold the canvas should turn green and show "high" message.

Is it possible using MediaRecorder or i haveto use AudioRecorder class. And how to work it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hye... why downvote.. This was totally appropriate question fulfilling all SO norms..??