# How to get amplitude of sound recorded via Audio Recorder

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder

I want to get the amplitude of recorded sound via audio recorder after every 1 second. But I am not getting any clue.

Secondly can we record sound from both  audio recorder as well as media recorder same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018794/record-sound-in-android-and-read-amplitude for the first part

Comment: more proper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066470/how-to-check-strength-intensity-of-audio-while-recording

Comment: #KPBird and #Jeremy D Both post are using Media Recorder and in media recorder there is a method getMaxAmplitude() but I am using audio Recorder...

Answer (score -1):

You may use  getSampleRate () method. It returns value in hz.

Comment: You can't convert HZ to volume.